# Power BI Pivot Columns Issue

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery

My data looked like:

[image]

---

After Pivoting in Power BI - Power Query, my data now looks like:

[image]

---

How can I get rid of those null values so that my looks likes this ? --->

[image]

---

P.S --> I have tried the "DON'T AGGREGATE" method while Pivoting

Comment: Please paste sample data as copiable text in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct I tried the same and got the same results - [image]

You have to select "ques" column and pivot values must be "ans".

`#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Id", Int64.Type}, {"ques", type text}, {"ans", type text}}), #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[ques]), "ques", "ans")`

[image]